# Cloudant database - Organize data columns

Tags: cloudant

I am using cloudant NoSQL database to store the historical data. I want the attributes in data column in a separate column. Please help!

[Data in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yUI4.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data has this form:

```
{
  d: {
    id: 'xyz',
    ts: 123,
    ax: 'abc'
  }
}
```

Cloudant's grid view only renders keys at the top of the object tree. If you stored data like this:

```
{
  id: 'xyz',
  ts: 123,
  ax: 'abc'
}
```

then the grid view would show id/ts/ax in their own columns.